# PHP, JS and CSS autocomplete is terrible in vs code… why?

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense

VS Code is great in nearly everything, except for autocompletion. Am I missing a plugin, am I missing something ? Is it being fixed ?

I've tried all top rated plugin for each language.

CSS : it does not suggest classes from other files, even opened ones.

PHP : intellisense, Crane and intelephense are kinda OK bug miss out a lot of definition… even from variables declared on the same file. (I have to use PHP 5, it might explain the problem)

JS : more surprisingly, even JS isn't great. There's a lot of missing methods… like "parentNode", "children", "classList.contains" and countless more…

Why is it so average, when the rest of the software is top notch ?

Is there any steps to improve the situation ?

Do I have to switch to PHPstorm ?

Thanks

Comment: I use PHP Intelephense in a daily basis and auto-completion suggestions are pretty good. Can you provide a short single-file example that illustrates the issue? (I take it for granted that you try all these extensions within a workspace...)

Comment: This for instance. VsCode can't find $aProducts.

    `<?php  
    $aProducts = $aProductsByCategory[$category_id];  

    foreach($aProducts as $oProduct){  
        die;  
    }`

Comment: [This is what I get](https://i.imgur.com/XYYnzzK.png) with Intelephense (assuming that's what you mean). As far as I know Intelephense is written in TypeScript so the version of your PHP interpreter should not be an issue.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up two problems : here, try the "go to definition". In my head, these are part of the same stuff… but it's not. Sorry !

Comment: I've created another post for the question above. Still, most autocomplete (especially in CSS) are very chancy

Comment: For what it's worth I feel your hurt. It feels completely random to me. Some times I think it's getting worse.

Comment: It is still the worst in 2024. `$object->` (ctrl+space) yields, wait for it, `$_COOKIE` `$ENV`, `$FILES` as suggestions. Unbelievable.